# Atomic variables other than c++11 and boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I currently require an atomic variable to cleanly exit my multi threaded program. 
On receiving a signal(such as SIGINT), the atomic variable is set to false, my threads exit, join the main program and I have a clean exit.

I however cannot use C++11 (building with C++ 11 causes too many compile errors).
My current boost library(ver 1.51) dosen't support atomic variables.

1. Do I have any other options available?
2. Do I even require an atomic variable, since it is set only at one location and read everywhere else

Comment: Maybe you should check *why* you get compiler errors when building with C++11 enabled, maybe it's just a missing header file? Also, I would argue that a simple boolean variable would suffice.

Comment: I agree with @JoachimPileborg, in 2015, c++11 **must** compile.

Comment: The parts that give the compiler error are totally unrelated to the problem( and more time consuming to fix than time I currently possess)  @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Is C++11 not backward compatible with C++03?

Comment: @rozina: Not perfectly, but I suspect the cause is code that was already illegal under C++03, but tolerated by the compiler back then. An important design goal of C++11 was to not break _correct_ code. If incorrect code now causes errors, that would generally be considered an improvement.

Comment: I understand that - at the moment - this matter is more pressing than making your Program  c++11 compliant (signal handling is actually unrelated to c++11 anyway), but I'd suggest you start fixing those errors bit by bit. For one, you are missing quite a lot of handy features, second, turning on c++11 even for pure 03 code might speed up your application noticably and sooner or later, you will have to move on anyway, if you want to use third party libraries.

Comment: @MSalters: Out of curiosity, can you give an example, where compiling in c++11 mode detects additional errors in c++03 code? That would help in some discussions. Missing headers, as mentioned by Joachim and maybe narrowing in braced initialization  are about the only examples I can think of off hand.

Answer (score 0):

So far I know that version of boost library should support atomic variables.

Give a look in  boost/interprocess/detail/atomic.hpp

Comment: boost atomic was introduced 1.53 onwards

Comment: In fact what I am suggersting is something 'stolen' from the implementation of boost::interprocess back in version 1.38

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the type you are supposed to use in signal handlers in C++03 as well as in c++11/14 is `sig_atomic_t`.

Signal handlers have even stronger requirements on allowed types than threads, because they must not block.

Also, while pre c++11 didn't have a multithreaded memory model, it was possible to write threadsafe code (e.g. according to the POSIX standard) for decades. So if you are using pthreads anyway, chances are you don't have to worry about what the pure c++03 standard guarantees  (or rather what it doesn't guarantee) but you rather should look at the POSIX and/or gcc documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Do I even require an atomic variable, since it is set only at one location and read everywhere else?

For a flag, which is set in signal handler, it is sufficient to use `volatile bool` (or `volatile int`) type. `Atomic` adds nothing in that case.